# Orange Sediment on top of water heater

Tags: water-heater

[image: Orange Dust on top of Water Heater]I have what looks like orange dust around one of the connectors on my water heater.  Can anyone tell me what that is and do I need to get a plumber in to address.

Comment: That... is a H/W tank that's going to fail in less than a year.

Answer (score 1):

That's galvanic corrosion.

It happens because your plumbing has two sufficiently dissimilar metals (likely copper and steel) in direct contact in the presence of a conducting fluid (your water).

Assuming the corrosion has not overly damaged your appliance already, you need to use a dielectric union when attaching your plumbing to your appliance.

Any competent plumber should be aware of this and it's a pretty easy fix. You can also DIY it if you're comfortable with pipe soldering!